# Audio doesn't play. Django, DEBUG = False

Tags: python, django, audio

Have a problem with audio playing again. Now in deploy with DEBUG = False.
This is my settings:

```
    STATIC_ROOT = '/home/bootuz/final/myapp/static/'

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/bootuz/final/audio/'

    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

This code I added to `urls.py`

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Template:

```
<audio id="player" preload="auto">
                <source src="{{ showword.audio.url }}" type="audio/mpeg">
                </audio>
                <button id="player_button" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"><img src="{% static 'images/audio.png' %}" alt="Play">
                </button>
```

And in the console I see this error:

[image]
Could you tell me, guys, what is wrong?

Comment: Have you configured your server to serve static files?

Comment: Do you mean `collectstatic`?

Comment: Django does not serve static files in production mode. Use your webserver for that.

Comment: It's working now! I didn't know where to look for the solution of the problem, thank you, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated in the comments, serving static files using Django is not advisable. In fact, [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) has this to say about the `static()` function:

> **This is not suitable for production use!** For some common deployment strategies, see [Deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/).

And further notes that:

> This helper function **works only in debug mode** and only if the given
>   prefix is local (e.g. /static/) and not a URL (e.g.
>   http://static.example.com/).
>
> Also this helper function only serves the actual STATIC_ROOT folder;
>   it doesn’t perform static files discovery like
>   django.contrib.staticfiles.

Please refer to the [linked documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/deployment/) for common scenarios of serving static files in production.